# is it possible to show files linked to detail record on the master record?

Tags: sharing, related-list, visibility

is it possible to show files that are linked to a detail record on the master record?

For example, I have an account__c record (AccountA) and a contact__c record (contactA), I attach a file to ContactA and I want to be able to see the file in the related list of files on the master record (Account A)

Comment: It is possible by adding custom VF page which will have attachments list and add it to your master record by editing the page layout.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [Trigger on `ContentDocumentLink`](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_content_triggers.htm):

> To customize file sharing behavior, define an Apex trigger for the
>   ContentDistribution or ContentDocumentLink objects. The
>   ContentDistribution object represents a file shared externally. A
>   ContentDocumentLink represents a file shared with an internal object,
>   such as a user, group, or record.

Answer (score 1):

Use a trigger on attachment to populate a junction object linking the Contact's account and the attachment. Put this related list on the page layout. You'll have two related list: Attachments and "Child Attachments".

You could link the account's attachment with the junction object as well and keep only one related list, but then you would have to create a custom button in order to create attachments on the account.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom visualforce page to query all attachments of child records and assemble a pageblockTable and embed this visualforce page on the page layout.

Comment: Same thing I said in my comment

Comment: oh. That's true. Create an answer and then I'll delete this one =D